# Entity Framework Remove or Add to Match List

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a table as so:

**Inventory Table**

- InventoryID (Primary Key)
- PersonID (Foreign Key)
- CarID (Foreign Key)

So on the front end it shows a list of cars, the user uses a checkbox to select the cars in their inventory.

If they unselect a vehicle and reselect it, it will no longer have the InventoryID.

In the end I will have a list with the correct field names, but I need the database rows to match that list by removing vehicles from the db which are not on that list and adding new ones which are on the list, and I need it to check by the PersonID + CarID combination, because the InventoryID may have been lost by unselecting and reselecting a vehicle.

The only way I can think of to do this would be to:

- Pull the inventory table and loop through it
- Check each vehicle to see if it is in the List
- Either Remove, Insert or do nothing

The downside of this though is each remove/insert would be a new query on top of the query to get the list itself.  I was wondering if there was a way in Entity Framework to do something like Match a List or Collection.

Comment: add the code you used

Comment: I haven't used any code yet, I'm trying to see if there is something already built into Entity Framework first.

Comment: `If they unselect a vehicle and reselect it, it will no longer have the InventoryID` what you mean?

Comment: when they first load from the db it will have an InventoryID, but if they check a box then that association won't yet have an InventoryID, so if they uncheck a box and check it again, the InventoryID won't exist anymore in that List, so I can't use InventoryID to check the db, I have to check by the other two fields

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need, Try this:

First check the `Inventory table` with `PersonID` of the user logged in as :

```
 var Inventory = (from r in db.Inventory where r.PersonID== userID select r).ToList();
```

This list contains all the vehicles list of the `user` no loop through it with the `list with the correct field names` and remove which are not in `Inventory`

consider `NewList` has the list with the correct field names, then

```
foreach(var item1 in Inventory)
{
    foreach(var item2 in NewList){
    { 
         if(item1.CarID == item2.CarID) // true only if old vehicle exist
         {
              // break from loop
              break;
         }
         else{
              // remove item1 from Inventory
              db.inventory.remove(item1);
              db.SaveChanges();
         }
    }
}
```

and you need one more add new vehicles to database

```
foreach(var item2 in NewList){
{
    foreach(var item1 in Inventory)
    { 
         if(item1.CarID == item2.CarID) // true only if old vehicle exist
         {
              // break from loop
              break;
         }
         else{
              //code add item2 to Inventory
              db.inventory.add(item2);
              db.SaveChanges();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this will have multiple add and remove queries, I was hoping there would be built in functionality in Entity Framework to minimize the queries but do the same task.

Comment: you can try deleting all datas in which `item1.CarID == item2.CarID` and add the list with the correct field names